# How can we resolve this by using selenium with robot frameworkTypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_log_path'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, logging, service, path, typeerror

I am using robot framework in my VS code and i have written one web automation testcase but while running the code i'm getting one error type error WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_log_path'
want to resolve the type error WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_log_path'